# While loop with multiple conditions in C

Tags: c, while-loop, getchar

I'm trying to read a character that has to be 'C' or 'n'.
In case it is not, print an error and ask for another char.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int c;
    printf("Enter the character: ");

    c = getchar();

    while (!(c=='C' && c=='n')){
            printf("Wrong!.\n");
            printf("Enter the character: ");
            c = getchar();  
    }

    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

And what I get is:

> Enter the character: s
>   Wrong!
>   Enter the character: Wrong!
>   Enter the character:

Like it is checking twice in the while loop.

Comment: use `scanf()` instead of `getchar()` . Also, the consition`!(c=='C' && c=='n')` doesnt make any sense  at all! how can `c` be `'n'` and `'C'` at the same time?!

Comment: I changed the condition to `while(c!='C' || c!='n')`.
So why can't I use getchar()? I thought it was for getting only one character and that's what I want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getchar()` is used for character by character input control.  You could still use `getchar()`, but you have to handle all the characters from the keyboard.  You can do this by ignoring the characters you do not care about.

I would also restructure your loop do be a do-while loop instead of a while loop

To modify your code to trap for upper and lower case A-Z you can do the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int c;
    printf("Enter the character: ");

    do {
        c = getchar(); 

        // ignore non a-z or non A-Z
        if( c < 'A' || ( c >'Z' && c < 'a' ) || c > 'z' ) {
            continue;
        }

        // look for the characters you care about
        if( c=='C' || c=='n') {
             break;
        }

        // now we only have incorrect characters that are 
        // only upper or lower case
            
        printf("%c Wrong!\n", (char)c );
        printf("Enter the character: ");

    } while (1);

    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Although I have not tested this...  You should get something like:

> Enter the character: s Wrong!
>
> Enter the character: t Wrong!
>
> Enter the character: C

When you enter "s-=+t\n01234C" .

**Note:** '\n' I am using to denote a carriage return entered from the keyboard

Answer (score 3):

Two things:

1) You are pressing a character and then hitting enter. That's two characters. If you want to read a whole line, don't use `getchar`.

2) Your conditional makes no sense. It will never be the case that `c` is both equivalent to `'C'` and equivalent to `'n'`, so you're testing something that cannot be. Your loop will never end.

Comment: ok. So I changed the condition to
    while (c!='C' && c!='n')
Now should I use scanf to get just the first char?